# How can I solve an image add issue on Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, image, storage, laravel-8

I have an issue with my Laravel8 project.

In my project, a user can post an add with an image. The image is well saved in the database but it's not displaying. And on my Console, I do have a 404 error message.

[image: 404 error message]

Here is my code in my migration file :

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddColumnImageUrlToOffersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('offers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //store images
            $table->string('image_url');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('offers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //drop the columns
            $table->dropColumn('image_url');
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my code in my layout file :

```
            <div class="w-1/2 rounded shadow overflow-hidden">
            <img class="object-cover w-full h-96" src="{{asset($offer->image_url)}}" alt="" srcset="">
        </div>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your storage folder permissions
if you are on localhost try `777`
if you are on server you can try `755`

Create symbolic link

```php
php artisan storage:link
```

Specify a public disk, example

```php
$path = $request->file('file')->store(
    'offer_images/'.$request->user()->id, 'public'
);
```

Retrieve file

```php
$url = Storage::url('file.jpg');
```

Since you are getting `404 Not Found` try retrieving file with domain

```php
$url = env('APP_URL').Storage::url('file.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

I could give you more info if you were to include the controller file, but usually, when you save a file via controller, it usually saves on storage folder on public directory. In simple terms, you probably need to do something like :

```
<img class="object-cover w-full h-96" src="{{asset('/storage/' . $offer->image_url)}}" alt="" srcset="">
```

If this does not work, please update the post with controller code, so we can check how you're storing the image. If you're feeling adventurous, feel free to take a look at storage folder on public directory any see if you can figure out what the appropriate url should be

Update:
After looking at your controller it seems like you're not storing the image in the [public disk][1]. By default laravel sores the files in private disk. To store the image to public disk, simply rewrite the $path like this:
`$path=$request->file('img')->store('offer_images', 'public'); //Public being the name of disk`

Now run `php artisan storage:link` if you haven't already. Once that is done, the following code should work perfectly

```
<img class="object-cover w-full h-96" src="{{asset('/storage/' . $offer->image_url)}}" alt="" srcset="">
```

Note: Laravel stores the image in `/storage/app/public` when you specify public disk as your storage. The folder is the linked to `/public/storage`. That is why you have to prefix the image url with `/storage/`
[1]: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Here is my Controller code :